# Javascript How to reverse space separated strings

Tags: javascript

The code below should reverse all the characters in a sentence, but it is unable to do so. This is child's play to me but at this moment it's not compiling. Can anyone figure out the issue?

Let's say:

> "Smart geeks are fast coders".

The below code should reverse the above string as follows:

> "trams skeeg era tsaf sredoc"

```
function solution(S){   
    var result = false;

    if(S.length === 1){
        result = S;
    }

    if(S.length > 1 && S.length < 100){
        var wordsArray = S.split(" "),
            wordsCount = wordsAray.length,
            reverseWordsString = '';

        for(var i = 0; i< wordsCount; i++){
            if(i > 0){
               reverseWordsString = reverseWordsString + ' ';
            }
            reverseWordsString = reverseWordsString + wordsAray[i].split("").reverse().join("");
        }
        result = reverseWordsString;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: you should expect others to put as much effort into their answers as you put into your question, and right now that is pretty much **no effort**. You could at least format your code so it is readable, you need to make it as **easy for someone to answer as possible!**

Comment: Have you tried to run the code? If yes, what error message do you receive?

Comment: `wordsArray` is not the same as `wordsAray`. Open a debug console in your browser and read the error messages.

Comment: yes i tried it does not print anything (tenbit) and that was typo sergiu

Comment: @Age : Thank you. I'll keep this in mind next time.I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the result you're looking for.

```
function reverseWords(s) {
  return s.replace(/[a-z]+/ig, function(w){return w.split('').reverse().join('')});
}
```

Comment: Thanks.This looks nice.Let me try out this.

Comment: @AbhishekDalakoti please make sure to accept the most helpful answer, so that future readers may find your question even more helpful

Comment: Sure thing.I'll do that.

Comment: Glad I could help, and yes regex is a nice solution for a problem like this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function reverseWords(s) {
    var arr = s.split(" ");
    s = '';
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        s += arr[i].split('').reverse().join('').toLowerCase() + " ";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Wouldn't that do the job for you? Basically it just converts the string into an array, by splitting it on space. Then it loops over the array, adds every string reversed to a new string, and then it converts it to lowercase. For faster speed (nothing you would notice), you can just call `newStr.toLowerCase()` after the loop, so it will do it once instead of every time.

Comment: Thanks Snorlax but not satisfying.

Comment: @AbhishekDalakoti It does the job though, right? It's easier to read, it's less code, and all you need to do, is throw it into a function.

Comment: @AbhishekDalakoti Check out my edit. I threw it into a function for you. How does the answer by DigiDamsel "look nice" compared to mine? I doubt you even know what his does, to be honest.

Comment: @Yes I'm dumb Sir.I do not know anything.